# For the function $f(x) = |x|^3$, $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, $f \notin C^{3}(\mathbb{R})$, but is $f \in C^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for $n \geq 4$?

Tags: derivatives

For the function $f(x) = |x|^3$, I know that $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and that $f \notin C^{3}(\mathbb{R})$, since there is a discontinuity at zero for the third derivatives $-6$ and $6$. However, after this all derivatives are zero. Hence, is it true that $f \in C^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for $n \geq 4$? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out $f^{(3)}$ is not defined at $0$, so how $f^{(3)}$ could be differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

As a reminder, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{C}^{n+1}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\mathcal{C}^n(\mathbb{R})$.